# Powershell: convert string to number

Tags: string, powershell

I have an Array where some drive data from WMI are captured:

```
$drivedata = $Drives | select  @{Name="Kapazität(GB)";Expression={$_.Kapazität}}
```

The Array has these values (2 drives):

```
@{Kapazität(GB)=1.500} @{Kapazität(GB)=1.500}
```

and just want to convert the 1.500 into a number 1500

I tried different suggestions I found here, but couldn't get it working:

`-Replace ".","" and  [int]`   doesn't work.
I am not sure if regex would be correct and how to do this.

Comment: How do you get the data from WMI? When I use `Get-WmiObject Win32_logicaldisk` the type of the size attribute value is an integer. So it might be better to fix that "problem"?

Comment: Basic maths: 1.5 * 1000 = 1500. Maybe you are labelling your properties wrong and that's why the number is not what you expect(TB vs GB)?

Comment: @OcasoProtal: I am using the Object: `code $Data = Get-ClusterSharedVolume -Cluster $Clustername | select -Expand SharedVolumeInfo | select FriendlyVolumeName , @{n="Kapazität";e={"{0:N0}" -f ($_.Partition.Size/1GB)}} `

Comment: @Raf: the script ran ok as Long as the Capacity was below 1.000 GB :-) Unfortunately its hard for me to find the proper formatting for the variable - May you have a look to my comment above?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Simply divide the Variable containing Numbers as a string by 1. PowerShell automatically convert the result to an integer.

> $a = 15; $b = 2; $a + $b --> 152

But if you divide it before:

> $a/1 + $b/1 --> 17

Answer (score 64):

Simply casting the string as an `int` won't work reliably. You need to convert it to an `int32`. For this you can use the .NET `convert` class and its `ToInt32` method. The method requires a `string` (`$strNum`) as the main input, and the `base number` (`10`) for the number system to convert to. This is because you can not only convert to the decimal system (the `10` base number), but also to, for example, the binary system (base 2).

Give this method a try:

```
[string]$strNum = "1.500"
[int]$intNum = [convert]::ToInt32($strNum, 10)

$intNum
```

Comment: What happens when the string isn't an int... this will blow up no?

Comment: This will blow up if the string is not a number.
e.g. [int]$intNum = [convert]::ToInt32("not a number", 10)
Exception calling "ToInt32" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find any recognizable digits."

Answer (score 11):

Since this topic never received a verified solution, I can offer a simple solution to the two issues I see you asked solutions for.

1. Replacing the "." character when value is a string

The string class offers a replace method for the string object you want to update:

Example:

```
$myString = $myString.replace(".","")
```

2. Converting the string value to an integer

The system.int32 class (or simply [int] in powershell) has a method available called "TryParse" which will not only pass back a boolean indicating whether the string is an integer, but will also return the value of the integer into an existing variable by reference if it returns true.

Example:

```
[string]$convertedInt = "1500"
[int]$returnedInt = 0
[bool]$result = [int]::TryParse($convertedInt, [ref]$returnedInt)
```

I hope this addresses the issue you initially brought up in your question.

Comment: The safest solution... (y)

Answer (score 2):

Replace all but the digits in the string like so:

```
$messyString = "Get the integer from this string: -1.500 !!"
[int]$myInt = $messyString -replace '\D', ''
$myInt
# PS > 1500
```

The regex `\D` will match everything except digits and remove them from your string.

This will work fine for your example.

Answer (score 1):

I demonstrate how to receive a string, for example "-484876800000" and tryparse the string to make sure it can be assigned to a long. I calculate the Date from universaltime and return a string.  When you convert a string to a number, you must decide the numeric type and precision and test if the string data can be parse, otherwise, it will throw and error.

```
function universalToDate
{
 param (
    $paramValue
  )
    $retVal=""


    if ($paramValue)
    {
        $epoch=[datetime]'1/1/1970'
        [long]$returnedLong = 0
        [bool]$result = [long]::TryParse($paramValue,[ref]$returnedLong)
        if ($result -eq 1)
        {
            $val=$returnedLong/1000.0
            $retVal=$epoch.AddSeconds($val).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $retVal=$null
    }
    return($retVal)
 }
```

Answer (score -2):

It seems the issue is in "-f ($_.Partition.Size/1GB)}}"  If you want the value in MB then change the 1GB to 1MB.