# PowerShell: Converting String Representations of Numbers to Integers

Tags: powershell

I've tried really hard not ask this question, but I keep coming back to it as I'm not sure if I'm doing everything as efficiently as I can or if there might be problems under the hood. Basically, I have a CSV file that contains a number field, but it includes a decimal and values out to the ten-thousandths place, e.g. `15.0000`. All I need to do is convert that to a whole number without the decimal place.

I came across a [related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25383160/15243610), but the selected answer seems to cast doubt on casting the string representation directly to an integer data type - without explaining why.

> Simply casting the string as an `int` won't work reliably. You need to convert it to an `int32`.

I've haven't had much luck getting the `[System.Convert]` method to work, or doing something like `$StringNumber.ToInt32()`. I realize that once I save the data back to the `PSCustomObject` they'll be stored as strings, so at the end of the day maybe I'm making this even more complicated than necessary for my use case and I just need to reformat `$StringNumber`...but even that has caused me some problems.

Any ideas on why casting wouldn't be reliable or better ways to handle this in my case?

Examples of what I've tried:

```
PS > $StringNumber = '15.0000'

PS > [Convert]::ToInt32($StringNumber)
#MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ToInt32" with "1" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."

PS > [Convert]::ToInt32($StringNumber, [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
#MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ToInt32" with "2" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."

PS > $StringNumber.ToInt32()
#MethodException: Cannot find an overload for "ToInt32" and the argument count: "0".

PS > $StringNumber.ToInt32([CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
#MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "ToInt32" with "1" argument(s): "Input string was not in a correct format."

PS > $StringNumber.ToString("F0")
#MethodException: Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "1".

PS > $StringNumber.ToString("F0", [CultureInfo]::CurrentCulture)
#MethodException: Cannot find an overload for "ToString" and the argument count: "2".

PS > "New format: {0:F0}" -f $StringNumber
#New format: 15.0000
```

So basically what I've come up with is:

- Someone in 2014 said casting my `string` to an `int` wouldn't work reliably, even though it seems like the [Cast operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#cast-operator--) is actually doing a conversion
- The `ToInt32` methods don't like strings with decimals as the input
- Apparently [`String.ToString` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tostring?view=net-6.0) is useless
- Thanks to `String.ToString` and the [processing order of composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#processing-order), simple "reformatting" of my string representation won't work

In summary: **Is there a way to safely cast my `$StringNumber` into a whole number, and, if so, what's the most efficient way to do it on a large dataset?**

**Bonus Challenge:**
If anyone can make this work using the [`ForEach` *magic method*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.1#foreachstring-propertyname) then I'll buy you a beer. Here's some pseudo code that doesn't work, but would be awesome if it did. As far as I can figure out, there's no way to reference the current item in the collection when setting the value of a `string property`

```
#This code DOES NOT work as written
PS > $CSVData = Import-Csv .\somedata.csv
PS > $CSVData.ForEach('StringNumberField', [int]$_.StringNumberField)
```

Comment: Casting `[int]` should not be a problem... at least until you encounter a `[decimal]::MaxValue` or `[long]::MaxValue`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon is right. But you can do it the hard way too. `$d = [Convert]::ToDecimal($StringNumber, [CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
[System.Decimal]::ToInt32($d)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **If your string representation *can be interpreted as a number*, you *can* cast it to an integer, as long as the specific integer type used is large enough** to accommodate (the integer portion of) the value represented (e.g. `[int] '15.0000'`)

  - A string that **can *not* be interpreted as a number** or represents a number that is **too large** (or small, for negative numbers) for the target type, results in a ***statement-terminating* error**; e.g. `[int] 'foo'` or `[int] '444444444444444'`
  - Note that **PowerShell's *casts* and *implicit string-to-number conversions* use the [*invariant culture*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)**, which means that **only ever `.` is recognized as the decimal mark** (and `,` is effectively *ignored*, because it is interpreted as the thousands-grouping symbol), irrespective of the culture currently in effect (as reflected in `$PSCulture`).
  - As for **integer types** you can use (all of them - except the open-ended `[bigint]` type - support `::MinValue` and `::MaxValue` to determine the range of integers they can accommodate; e.g. `[int]::MaxValue`)

    - *Signed* integer types: `[sbyte]`, `[int16]`, `[int]` (`[int32]`), `[long]` (`[int64]`), `[bigint]`
    - *Unsigned* integer types: `[byte]`, `[uint16]`, `[uint]` (`[uint32]`), `[ulong]` (`[uint64]`) - but note that PowerShell itself uses only *signed* types natively in its calculations.
- **Casting to an integer type performs *half-to-even* midpoint *rounding***, which means that a string representing a value whose fractional part is `.5` is rounded to the nearest *even* integer; e.g. `[int] '1.5'` and `[int] '2.5'` *both* round to `2`.

  - To choose a **different midpoint rounding strategy**, use [`[Math]::Round()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Math.Round) with a [`System.MidpointRounding`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.MidpointRounding) argument; e.g.:

    ```
    [Math]::Round('2.5', [MidPointRounding]::AwayFromZero) # -> 3
    ```
  - To ***unconditionally* round up or down** to the nearest integer, use [`[Math]::Ceiling()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Math.Ceiling), [`[Math]::Floor()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Math.Floor), or [`[Math]::Truncate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Math.Truncate); e.g.:

    ```
    [Math]::Ceiling('2.5')    # -> 3
    [Math]::Floor('2.5')      # -> 2
    [Math]::Truncate('2.5')   # -> 2
    #
    [Math]::Ceiling('-2.5')   # -> -2
    [Math]::Floor('-2.5')     # -> -3
    [Math]::Truncate('-2.5')  # -> -2
    ```
  - Note: While the resulting number is *conceptually* an integer, *technically* it is a [`[double]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Double) or - with explicit `[decimal]` or integer-number-literal input - a [`[decimal]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Decimal).

---

As for the **bonus challenge**:

- With an integer-type cast:

```
[int[]] (Import-Csv .\somedata.csv).StringNumberField
```

<sup>Note: `(Import-Csv .\somedata.csv).StringNumberField.ForEach([int])` would work too, but offers no advantage here.</sup>

- With a `[Math]::*()` call and the [`.ForEach()` array method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays#foreach):

```
(Import-Csv .\somedata.csv).StringNumberField.ForEach(
  { [Math]::Round($_, [MidPointRounding]::AwayFromZero) }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Casting `[int]` as you explained, is something that would work *in most cases*, however it is also prone to errors. What if the number is higher than `[int]::MaxValue` ? The alternative you could use to avoid the exceptions would be to use the [`-as [int]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_type_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-as-operator) operator however there is another problem with this, if the value cannot be converted to integer you would be getting `$null` as a result.

To be safe that the string will be converted and you wouldn't get null as a result first you need to be 100% sure that the data you're feeding is correct or assume the worst and use `[math]::Round(..)` in combination with `-as [decimal]` or `-as [long]` or `-as [double]` (`∞`) to round your numbers:

```
[math]::Round('123.123' -as [decimal]) # => 123
[math]::Round('123.asd' -as [decimal]) # => 0
```

**Note:** I'm using round but `[math]::Ceiling(..)` or `[math]::Floor(..)` or `[math]::Truncate(..)` are valid alternatives too, depending on your expected output.

Another alternative is to use `[decimal]::TryParse(..)` however this would throw if there ever be something that is not a number:

```
$StringNumber = '15.0000'
$ref = 0
[decimal]::TryParse( $StringNumber, ([ref]$ref) )
[math]::Round($ref) # => 15
```

Using [Hazrelle's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70439635/powershell-converting-string-representations-of-numbers-to-integers?noredirect=1#comment124517092_70439635) advise would work too but again, would throw an exception for invalid input or *"Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."*

```
[System.Decimal]::ToInt32('123123123.123') # => 123123123
```

As for the Bonus Challenge, I don't think it's possible to cast and then set the rounded values to your CSV on just one go using [`ForEach(type convertToType)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_arrays?view=powershell-7.2#foreachtype-converttotype), and even if it was, it could also bring problems because of what was mentioned before:

```
$csv = @'
"Col1","Col2"
"val1","15.0000"
"val2","20.123"
"val3","922337203685477.5807"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

$csv.Col2.ForEach([int])
```

> Cannot convert argument "item", with value: "922337203685477.5807", for "Add" to type "System.Int32": "Cannot convert value "922337203685477.5807" to type "System.Int32".

Using `.foreach(..)` array method combined with a *script block* would work:

```
$csv.ForEach({
    $_.Col2 = [math]::Round($_.Col2 -as [decimal])
})
```

---

In case you wonder why not just use `[math]::Round(..)` over the string and forget about it:

```
[math]::Round('123.123') # => 123 Works!
```

But what about:

```
PS /> [math]::Round([decimal]::MaxValue -as [string])
7.92281625142643E+28

PS /> [math]::Round([decimal]([decimal]::MaxValue -as [string]))
79228162514264337593543950335
```